# How to establish mysql select queries for multiple conditions in a site search engine

Tags: php, search

I am attempting to create a site search engine on a site. The image below is an example of the query form:

[image]

The client can select all or just one of the options available... what i do not understand is how to query the database not knowing what options the client is going to select.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/p206x206/11667888_1171206346238543_964540638_n.jpg?oh=2846c6ad57fa5eb868a768a3abffefa7&oe=55949D8A

Comment: You have to provide a better description what exactly is your problem? Do you get the data already in a $_POST, $_GET array or do you use a framework?

Comment: Please show us that you tried. Show us your code, and ask precise questions. (And you should be able to edit your original post, instead of adding a comment :) )

Comment: please improve your question, add details and what is more important - post what you have tried so far

Comment: Hellow guys

So...see that image?

https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/p206x206/11667888_1171206346238543_964540638_n.jpg?oh=2846c6ad57fa5eb868a768a3abffefa7&oe=55949D8A

Comment: i received the all the values...and i need to show the houses, if a client select "concelho:guimaraes" or just select "reference"

Comment: What we're asking is php code, not photos :) We can see that you worked on html interfaces, but you seem to have pb with php code, so show us this php code.

Comment: CAN CONTACT ME FOR E-MAIL OR FACEBOOK?

ruimiguelmendesmelo1996@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You would use an `if(){}` for each condition to create the sql select query

```
if($varA == 'whatever' && $varB == 'whatever){$sql = 'SELECT AAA,BBB FROM THETABLE WHERE AAA=:THEID ORDER BY whatever'}
elseif($varA == 'whatever' && $varB == 'whatever){$sql = 'SELECT AAA,BBB FROM THETABLE WHERE AAA=:THEID ORDER BY whatever'}


    $selectqup = $db->prepare($sql);    
    $selectqup->bindValue(':THEID',$AAA,PDO::PARAM_INT);$selectqup->execute(); 
    $ct = $selectqup->rowCount();   

        while($row = $selectqup->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $??? = $row['???'];
        $??? = $row['???'];

        // run serps here

        }
```

Comment: yess i have to use one sql query for each condition?

Comment: you cant talk to me for facebook or something like that?

Comment: well you will need many `if(){}`... you have to tell the database what you want to return... the above example drives this search engine: http://www.s8wministries.org/audios.php?id=30 here

Comment: I am on a deadline... but if you take the time to study the example and then carefully consider your various conditions and create the statement it should work for you... try it and if it doesn't work come back here and add your attempted code and i'll review it.

Comment: this example it looks like my form, you cant talk with me for another way?

Comment: if ($concelhow=="" && $freguesiaw=="" && $tiponegociow=="" && $tipoimovelw=="" && $tipologiaw=="" && $garagemw=="" && $precominw=="" && $precomaxw=="" && $referenciaw==""){  
echo "Listar todos!"; }
elseif (($referenciaw=="" && $concelhow !=="") && ($referenciaw=="" && $concelhow !=="" && $freguesiaw=="")) {
echo $concelhow;}
elseif  ($referenciaw=="" && $concelhow !=="" && $freguesiaw!=="") {
echo $concelhow,$freguesiaw;}
elseif  ($referenciaw=="" && $concelhow =="" && $freguesiaw=="" && $tiponegociow!=="") {
  echo $tiponegociow; } 
 elseif ($referenciaw !=="") {
        echo $referenciaw;}

Comment: https://scontent-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t35.0-12/11663970_1171361986222979_780691034_o.jpg?oh=fdff607bdfe7919b1c498212d17816f3&oe=55959F49

Comment: This site is purposed to assist developers in finding and fixing issues in code they have written which for whatever reason is not functioning as desired. Basically you are asking me to provide instruction in programming... i simply to not have the time to do so... go test the example provided... it works and will meet your needs.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are quite right, I'm just a bit upset because I'm now on a long time and still did not get ..